# How to run tweakbox app on Xcode simulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

There is a tweaked app store called tweakbox for iPhone. I don't have any ios devices except my Macbook pro. I tried to run the tweakbox app using an Xcode device simulator (Virtual ios device). the tweakbox is successfully installed using the profile provided on their website (https://www.tweakboxapp.com/) but I can't install the apps from within the tweakbox. The install button doesn't do anything. it is the same for all the apps.

Did anyone ever try to do this?